# JSX expressions must have one parent element with conditional expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the curly brackets to include a javascript expression but whenever I include the curly brackets it gives out an error: JSX expressions must have one parent element. I think it has to do with my VSCODE.  I have gone through similar problems with the same error but I can't find a solution. Is there a way around it...

```
render () {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <Particles className='particles'params={ particlesOptions }/>

    <Navigation />
      { this.state.route === 'route'
        ? <Signin />  
        : <Logo />
          <Rank />

          <ImageLinkForm 
            onInputChange={ this.onInputChange }
            onButtonSubmit={ this.onButtonSubmit }
          />

          <FaceRecognition box={ this.state.box } imageUrl={ this.state.imageUrl }/>
      }
  </div>
);
```

}

Comment: You have to wrap `<Logo/ > <Rank /> ...` in another element.

Comment: Thank you, Emile and Felix, it worked. And I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your JSX expression has multiple elements at the 'top level' that are 'siblings' like you do here, you need to wrap all the JSX with `<>` at the beginning and `</>` at the end. This is called a Fragment, and it's needed just because of how JSX is defined and parsed. In your case, the `Logo` `Rank` `ImageLinkForm` `FaceRecognition` expression needs to be wrapped in a fragment.

BTW - some older answers use `<React.Fragment>`, but nowadays you can use `<>` and `</>`

Comment: Thank you Noam Bendelac, it worked and I understand.